# Bode plot starting from 180?

Tags: feedback, nmos, stability, bode-plot, phase-margin

[image]

This is an NMOS common source amplifier and I'm trying to calculate the Phase Margin, but it's starting from 180 instead of zero?

dose it mean I have poles at the origin or it's very stable?

Comment: Common Source is inverting = 180'

Comment: '  so it shows 60' margin

Answer (score 2):

If you have a non-inverting amplifier, then you are interested in the phase shift away from 0° as the frequency changes. If you have an inverting amplifier, then you are interested in the phase shift away from 180° as the frequency changes.

> *does it mean I have poles at the origin or it's very stable?*

No, it doesn't. An NMOS common source amplifier is an inverting amplifier (see above).